# Can't zoom scroll universe java 3d without objects dissapear

Tags: zooming, behavior, java-3d, orbit

Well, this is a bit annoying, when I try to zoom out, my objects start to dissapear and then go black merging with the background so I can't zoom out as much as desire, I'm using a OrbitBehavior and set the bounds and after that I stablish it to the viewingplatform of my universe like this:

```
 OrbitBehavior B = new OrbitBehavior(zonaDibujo);
 B.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 1000.0) );
 universo.getViewingPlatform().setViewPlatformBehavior(B);
```

Any ideas?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

This may have todo with the amount of memorie in use. Try to set up some memorie allocaters for the program before you run it

Example in CMD

Java -Xms1024M -Xmx8192M

were as

```
  Xms is the starting heap size 
  Xmz is the maximum heap size
```